# Dynamically add multiple images from input

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have the following code:

```
      var imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
    var patternLoader = document.getElementById("patternLoader");
    var canvas = document.getElementById('imageCanvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


  function handleImage(e) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function (event) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function () {
          canvas.width = img.width;
          canvas.height = img.height;
          ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        }
        img.src = event.target.result;
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
    };

    imageLoader.addEventListener("change", handleImage, false);
    patternLoader.addEventListener("change", handleImage, false);
```

How can I load one image over another from inputs and not replace them?

I want it to be like that http://i.gyazo.com/85c8c6bdcd2efcdd6a1c1b156000f204.png

Comment: You want the two images drawn on the canvas to be considered as two objects on your canvas?

Comment: i want it to be like that http://i.gyazo.com/85c8c6bdcd2efcdd6a1c1b156000f204.png

Comment: Do you want the new image always on top and that the canvas' size adjusts to the largest image?

Comment: I just want to dynamically load multiple images to canvas from inputs.

Comment: What kind of DOM elements are `imageLoader` and `patternLoader`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a crude way to add images dynamically. Declare an array to keep track on all your images and scale the canvas based on the largest image.

Since I didn't konw what kind of DOM elements the OP used for "imageLoader" and "patternLoader", I simply used an `<input>`-tag.

Just keep pasting URLs for images to add images to your canvas. The images will be drawn in the order as you add them.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var maxWidth = 0;
var maxHeight = 0;
var images = [];

var myInput = document.getElementById("myInput");
myInput.addEventListener('change',handleImage,false);

function handleImage(e) {
    var myImage = new Image();
    myImage.onload = function () {   
        if (myImage.width > maxWidth) {
            maxWidth = myImage.width;
        }
        if (myImage.height > maxHeight) {
            maxHeight = myImage.height;
        }
        canvas.width = maxWidth;
        canvas.height = maxHeight;
        images.push(myImage);
        drawImages();
    }
    myImage.src = e.target.value;
}

function drawImages() {
    for (var i = 0; i<images.length; i++) {
        ctx.drawImage(images[i],canvas.width/2-images[i].width/2,canvas.height/2-images[i].height/2);
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput"><br />
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: i'm using `input[type="file"]` elements and it gives me an error when i try to upload file `Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/fakepath/7dd84d70-768b-492b-88f7-a6c70f2db2e9.jpg`

Comment: Ah yes, see that information could have been useful in your question since that changes things a bit. My answer is not really applicable to local files (although you can still use the way of thinking with a global variable for the images and my drawImages() function). See this perhaps http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/